# Make DISTINCT choose between duplicates by some criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

**I have:** table like:

```
my_table
 |- id BIGINT(20)
 |- name VARCHAR(100) // there are a lot of DUPLICATES
 |- preferred TINYINT(1) 
 |- dependency_id INT(11)e
```

**I need:** Select all distinct names for dependency with id equals @id:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(name) FROM my_table WHERE dependency_id = @id
```

**Problem:** If there are at least two duplicates, I should choose one which has `preferred` field equals 1.

**Question:** *How to make `DISTINCT`  choose the row with the `preferred = 1`?*

Comment: If the name is duplicated, it should be the same when prefered=1 or prefered=0.

Comment: @segarci Means there can be two rows in `my_table` with `name = vehicle` but different `prefered` field values

Comment: What does it matter which 'name' it is if they are the same, and you select only the 'name' field? Please rephrase your question. I thought it was clear, but now it turns out that what you wrote is not what you mean.

Comment: BTW. `DISTINCT` operates on the entire selection of fields. So `DISTINCT(NAME)` is semantically wrong. It will accidentally work, but you make it look like `DISTINCT` is a function with NAME being the parameter, which is certainly not the case.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to choose one name with priority to `preferred`, then do:

```
SELECT name
FROM my_table
WHERE dependency_id = @id
ORDER BY preferred desc
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: @V_B . . . Your question is unclear.  You should edit the question and include sample data and desired results.